How can I reference a library I downloaded in MSYS2 in VS Code (Windows)?
I'm new to C++. I installed the C/C++ and C/C++ Extension Pack and following instructions to install MSYS2.
Through MSYS2 I downloaded mingw-w64-x86_64-crypto++ and verified that it is present (pacman -Q). I also confirm that the package is in the include directory (in my case: D:\msys64\mingw64\include\cryptopp).
I verified that VS Code was working (Hello World) using C/C++: g++.exe.
I am trying to include:
#include <cryptopp/sha.h>
#include <cryptopp/hmac.h>
#include <cryptopp/pbkdf2.h>

When I attempt to run the solution, I get an error even though the header file is in the MSYS2 directory:

cryptopp/sha.h: No such file or directory

How can I resolve this?
My c_cpp_properties.json reads as follows:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "D:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "D:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

I downloaded a short program that has a function (I commented out part of it afterward):
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <cryptopp/sha.h>
#include <cryptopp/hmac.h>
#include <cryptopp/pbkdf2.h>

using namespace CryptoPP;

int main() {
    std::string password = "my_password";
    std::string salt = "random_salt";
    unsigned int iterations = 10000; // Adjust iterations for desired strength
    unsigned int key_length = 32; // Desired key length in bytes

    byte key[key_length];

 /*   
    PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<SHA256> pbkdf;
    pbkdf.DeriveKey(key, key_length, (const byte*)password.data(), password.length(),
                   (const byte*)salt.data(), salt.length(), iterations);

    // Convert key to hex for display (optional)
    std::string hex_key;
    HexEncoder encoder;
    encoder.Attach(new StringSink(hex_key));
    encoder.Put(key, key_length);
    encoder.MessageEnd();

    std::cout << "Derived key: " << hex_key << std::endl;
*/ 
    return 0;
}


mingw-w64-x86_64-crypto++ is the wrong package for ucrt64. You wanted https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-crypto++?repo=ucrt64 and the install command is on that page: pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-crypto++

Also remember that your compiler does not use c_cpp_properties.json to compile your code. That file is just for Intellisense.

And finally you will need to edit your tasks.json to link to this library: /ucrt64/lib/libcryptopp.a

...but instead of specifying the full path, you'll just use -lcrypopp.

how are you building the code? If you're using code runner I'd recommend stopping that before it causes you any more trouble. If you're using tasks.json please show the contents of that file

@drescherjm - worked!  Only problem that remains is that cryptopp/pbkdf2.h does not exist in the package. I need to to figure this out. Maybe I sourced old code.

@AlanBirtles. I followed the instructions that Microsoft's C/C++ Extension suggested.  The package manager MSYS2 was suggested while I was setting up C++.

@chribonn your edit to provide a solution does not belong in the question. It should be posted as an answer instead. See Can I answer my own question?. Please move it.

@RemyLebeau Done and appended a comment that I was using the wrong library (see first comment post)

The corrected tasks.json that points to the correct library.  Added libcryptopp.a to the args array:
Another point to note is that I was downloading the wrong library: See first comment.
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "D:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "D:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\lib\\libcryptopp.a"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}

